# How to add a column after another column in sqlalchemy for mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, alembic

I have a table where I need to add column say a_1 after column a and the table structure is like column a,b,c,d? How can i add this?

Below query adds column after d but I want to add column after a?

```
def upgrade():
# ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
op.add_column('sample_table', sa.Column('a_1', mysql.JSON(), nullable=True, ))
# ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
# ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
op.drop_column('sample_table', 'a_1')
# ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Comment: Class `alembic.operations.BatchOperations` has a method `add_column(column, insert_before=None, insert_after=None)`. https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on [answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869855/21985362),
   alembic batch operation:

```py
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
  with op.batch_alter_table('sample_table') as batch_op:
    batch_op.add_column(
      sa.Column('a_1', ...),
      insert_after='a',
    )


def downgrade():
  op.drop_column('sample_table', 'a_1')
```

The feature [introduced](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog.html#change-1.4.0) with alembic `1.4.0`.
[Reference in docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.AbstractOperations.batch_alter_table).

= = =

2. The docs describe "recreate" argument.

In my case [postgres 15, alembic 1.7.4] the above doesn't work without explicit `recreate="always"`. It means a new table is created with all the data copied from existing one. The default `recreate="auto"` may perform the same actions.

```py
def upgrade():
  with op.batch_alter_table('sample_table', recreate='always') as batch_op:
    ...
```

= = =

3. Some other ways:

- sql dialect may allow `.. ADD COLUMN .. AFTER <existing column>` [like MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732461/21985362)
- recreate table with raw sql
- db management tools (I'm not familiar with)

Alembic allows raw sql execution with `op.execute()`: [more docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.execute).

Answer (score -4):

```
add_column(table_name, column, schema=None)
```

Issue an “add column” instruction using the current migration context.

e.g.:

```
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import Column, String

op.add_column('organization',
    Column('name', String())
)
```

The provided Column object can also specify a ForeignKey, referencing a remote table name. Alembic will automatically generate a stub “referenced” table and emit a second ALTER statement in order to add the constraint separately:

```
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import Column, INTEGER, ForeignKey

op.add_column('organization',
    Column('account_id', INTEGER, ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
)
```

Note that this statement uses the Column construct as is from the SQLAlchemy library. In particular, default values to be created on the database side are specified using the server_default parameter, and not default which only specifies Python-side defaults:

```
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import Column, TIMESTAMP, func

# specify "DEFAULT NOW" along with the column add
op.add_column('account',
    Column('timestamp', TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now())
)
```

Parameters
table_name – String name of the parent table.

column – a sqlalchemy.schema.Column object representing the new column.

schema – Optional schema name to operate within. To control quoting of the schema outside of the default behavior, use the SQLAlchemy construct quoted_name.

Source https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html